# Identifying Version of TFS via web interface

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to get the installed version of TFS 2017 when I only have access to its web interface via HTTP?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's an "About" link that appears on every page in the top right corner. It may be hidden within an ellipsis menu (*...*).

You'll get a version number there, like 15.112.26307.0.

The list for 2015 onward is:

- Team Foundation Server **2015**:

  - **RTM** - 14.0.23128.0
  - **Update 1** - 14.0.24712.0
  - **Update 2** - 14.95.25122.0
  - **Update 2.1** - 14.95.25229.0
  - **Update 3** - 14.102.25423.0
  - **Update 4** - 14.114.26403.0
- Team Foundation Server **2017**:

  - **RC1** - 15.103.25603.0
  - **RC2** - 15.105.25716.0
  - **RTM** - 15.105.25910.0
  - **Update 1 RC1** - 15.111.26117.0
  - **Update 1 RC2** - 15.112.26206.0
  - **Update 1 RTM** - 15.112.26301.0
  - **Update 1 RTM** - 15.112.26307.0
  - **Update 2 RC1** - 15.117.26526.0
  - **Update 2 RC2** - 15.117.26615.0
  - **Update 2 RTM** - 15.117.26714.0
  - **Update 3 RC1** - 15.117.26912.0
  - **Update 3** - 15.117.27024.0
- Team Foundation Server **2018**:

  - **RC1** - 16.121.26818.0
  - **RC2** - 16.122.26918.3
  - **RTM** - 16.122.27102.1
  - **Update 1** - 16.122.27409.2
  - **Update 2** - 16.131.27701.1
  - **Update 3** - 16.131.28106.2
- Azure DevOps Server **2019**:

  - **RTM** - 17.143.28511.3
  - **Update 1** - 17.153.29522.3
- Azure DevOps Server **2020**:

  - **RC1** - 18.170.30308.2
  - **RC2** - 18.170.30331.4
  - **RTM** - 18.170.30830.2
  - **Update 1** - 18.181.31230.2
- Azure DevOps Server **2022**:

  - **Update 0.1 Patch 1** - AzureDevOpsServer_20230602.5

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline#azure-devops-server-build-numbers