# Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to send a REST request to TFS?

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

I am trying to create tasks in my local TFS via REST API, but I always get a 404 error. Does anybody know if I am using the correct URI, what the correct URI would be, or if I'm doing anything else wrong?

I followed various tutorials on https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1 and downloaded their example project for this reason. But none of that helped me get rid of my 404. 
The base URI of the TFS is correct, I can work on it via browser.

```
JsonPatchDocument createStoryRequest = new JsonPatchDocument();
createStoryRequest.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
          Operation = Operation.Add,
          Path = "/fields/System.Title",
          Value = storyToCreate.Fields.Title
        }
    );

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", ApiCredentials.tfsAuthenticationToken))));
  Task postJsonTask = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
      "https://my_tfs_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=4.1",
      createStoryRequest))
    {
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      System.Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
  });
  Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { postJsonTask});
}
```

I expected a story/task/anything to be created on my TFS, but no matter what I try, I always get a 404.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to everybody for helping me! The solution was the version of the API: TFS2018 only supports API version 4.0, and will give the 404 error described, when another API version is given. 
[Identify the version for your TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937655/identifying-version-of-tfs-via-web-interface)
[Identify the API version](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/19#issuecomment-383709013)
And use the following code (and the RestSharp NuGet package):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://my_tfs_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/PROJECTNAME/_apis/wit/workitems/$User Story?api-version=4.0");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("", ApiCredentials.tfsAuthenticationToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "[{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/fields/System.Title\", \"value\": \"" + storyToCreate.Fields.Title + "\" }]", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Your getting a 404 because "page not found" that's what a 404 is. Can you hit the URL on your browser?

Comment: In the tfs url did you put also `:8080`?

Comment: I got it to return the list of projects to me. just replaced the line with: using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(ApiCredentials.tfsBaseUri + "_apis/projects"))

Comment: @Liam No, I can not hit the url in my browser: 403 forbidden. (because I turned on token authentication, and I can't token authenticate with my browser)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No because I use token authentication, which only works on ssl, which means the correct port would be 443. which I tried with the exact same result.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk More correctly: I tried it via http instead of https, and added the 8080, which gave the same result on my current request, and a 'unauthorized: token authentication only works on https' on the on thats working.

Comment: This is a simple connection issue, something about your url and how you are connecting is different between where your using it and where it doesn't work. This could be any number of different variables from firewall or proxy setting to simply not having an internet connection. The best person to fix this is you

Comment: @Liam As I commented: It works for getting the list of projects. So I just need the correct URI, or some other error with the program (for example how I use post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API Description of Version 4.1 that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) the correct POST command is:

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=4.1
```

So compared to your sample I think you miss the project name after the collection.

So it should be something like this:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
      "https://my_tfs_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/PROJECTNAME/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=4.1",
      createStoryRequest))
    {
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      System.Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
```

**Edit**:
So the URL has to be adjusted to include the Project Name:
"https://my_tfs_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/PROJECTNAME/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=4.1" where "PROJECTNAME" should be the name of your team project.
If used without a project name you seem to get a 404, if you specify a non existing project you get some error that this project does not exist.

**Edit2:**
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937655/identifying-version-of-tfs-via-web-interface) your version of TFS relates to TFS 2018 RTM, which is supporting the REST API in version 4.0 according to [comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/19#issuecomment-383709013) on github.
The examples used so far use api version 4.1, which apparently ist not supported.
The docs for the REST API before 4.1 is a bit hidden, however this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/work-items?view=tfs-2018#create-work-item) should provide the correct specification. It seems to create you have to provide a PATCH request:

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
```

The body of the request should contain the values of the fields in the JSON format:

```
[
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": { string }
    "value": { string or int, depending on the field }
},
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value":
    {
        "rel": { string },
        "url": { string },
        "attributes":
        {
            { name/value pairs }
        }
    }
}
```

]

The api-version should therefore be 4.0.

**EDIT3: (by question poster)** also my mediatype was wrong. "application/json" will result in a 'bad request' response. The correct media type is "application/json-patch+json".

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time! Yeah, that is the exact link I posted in my description. Unfortunately the answer is still: 404.

Comment: Hi
sorry about the link, I missed that one.
Did you of course replace the "PROJECTNAME" string with your actual project name and try it out? At least on my instance of Azure DevOps this worked, while leaving the ProjectName caused a 404 like you have.

Comment: No problem, I'm thankful to get any answers! I replaced the PROJECTNAME with my projectname. Is there a problem with projects that have a space in the middle? My projectname is "Example Project". Are you using the cloud version? I am using it locally, the 2018 version 16.122.27102.1 (Tfs2018)

Comment: "https://my_local_computername/tfs/DefaultCollection/Example%20Project/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=4.1" returns a 404.

Comment: "https://my_local_computername/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects" returns the Example Project correctly.

Comment: I only tried so far with sending the POST Request directly via Postman and via C#, in there I just specified the project with a space (and not with %20).
You should as well be able to specify the project id instead of the name there in case to go around the space, maybe that helps.
I do work against Azure DevOps and not TFS

Comment: Ok, just tried to replace the %20 with a space. Unfortunately: 404. But what do you mean by 'sending the POST Request directly via Postman'? Is there some other way this could work better? Do you have a code example? Or do I need to kitnap an actual Postman? (I am getting despreate, I am willing to try it ;D)

Comment: Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) is an application that let's you easily send HTTP requests wich makes it easy to test REST API calls and verify whether they are correct/return what you expect without having to write some C# application or so. If the same url works in there it would mean your C# application has some issue (maybe some configuration there or so)

Comment: @StefanRiegler I made an edit to my answer, as I believe your version of TFS does not support the API 4.1 but only 4.0 where the interface was a bit different.

Comment: Sorry to drop my professionalism for a moment but: you magnificient bastard! You did it! (well at least now I get a 400: bad request) but that was seriously it! Now I just have to get that json stuff to work and I'm gold! Thank you so much!

Comment: Very good, no problem, glad I could help.
I assume the bad request comes from some parameters in JSON body that might need to be in a different format or so, I hope you get it running soon :-)

Comment: Thanks again for helping me! Got the 'bad request' away, when I realized, that Postman can generate c# code, that used RestSharp as basis. Should I post the working code somewhere here? As help for future readers? (I'm new to being an active user on stackoverflow ^^. Don't know the best practices yet)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, it probably is best if you edit your original answer with the resolution that solved it, so it can be seen at first glance